# Using arr.push() to add an object to an array replacing existing value instead of adding new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

Currently trying to render a list of components that expands/shrinks as values are added/removed from an array of a custom object type. However, whenever I make the called to push a value into a new array and then pass that into a hook, the array simply replaces the previous value rather than making the list of objects longer. Any help appreciated.

```js
// My interface
interface IAddedSkill {
    id: string,
    level: Level,
    name: string,
}

const [potentialSkills, setPotentialSkills] = useState<IAddedSkill[]>([]);
let addedSkills: IAddedSkill[] = [];

function handleAddedSkills(addedSkill: IAddedSkill) {
        addedSkills.push(addedSkill);
        setPotentialSkills(addedSkills);
    }
    ...some code in between
    // Rendering the react component using this hook
    {potentialSkills.map(skill => (
          <Chip label={skill.name} onDelete={() => handleDelete(skill)} />
          ))}
```

Can anyone see something I'm doing wrong that would cause this behaviour?

Edit:
Thanks for all the answers, the implementation I used that resolved the issue was changing the handleAddSkills function to:

```js
function handleAddedSkills(addedSkill: IAddedSkill) {
    setPotentialSkills([...potentialSkills, addedSkill]);
}
```

I also completely removed any reference to the addedSkills list and removed the declaration.

Comment: Variables declared at the top level of a component will be redeclared on every render, if you need to maintain the value through renders use a `ref` or state. But why not just add to the state array? `setPotentialSkills(prev => [...prev, addedSkill]);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to push an item to array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71724509/correct-way-to-push-an-item-to-array-in-javascript)

Comment: also [how to set state array using react hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100863/how-to-set-state-array-using-react-hooks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is redeclaring the variable `addedSkills` every render with an empty array， so you are `setPotentialSkills` with `addedSkills` which's length always equals 1.

You can just remove `addedSkills`, and invoke `setPotentialSkills` like:

```
setPotentialSkills((previousSkills) => [...previousSkills, addedSkill]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make `addedSkills` a state variable otherwise it will get overwritten every time your component renders.

```
let [addedSkills, setAddedSkills] = useState([])
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `addedSkills` array and update the `potentialSkills` state directly:

```
const [potentialSkills, setPotentialSkills] = useState<IAddedSkill[]>([]);

function handleAddedSkills(addedSkill: IAddedSkill) {
    setPotentialSkills((oldSkills) => [...oldSkills, addedSkills]);
}
```